# DojoX Flash streaming

Tags: flash, dojo, wowza

When I use jwplayer with following config everything is OK.

```
jwplayer('someId').setup({
        'flashplayer': '/js/jwplayer/player.swf',
        'file':        'awesome.flv',
        'streamer':    'rtmp://some.server.com:1934/vod',
        'width':       '220',
        'height':      '190'
    });
```

When I use dojo with following config:

```
new Flash({
    path:   'rtmp://some.server.com:1934/vod?file=awesome.flv' ,
    width:    220,
    height:   190
    }, this.someId);
```

Flash place holder is visible, but no controls to play stream and in the console I can see error that have no meaning for me...

```
Building SWF failed.
[Break On This Error]   

comboPendingTimer = null;

dojo.js (line 648)
```

What is wrong with dojo flash config? Another thing is how to tell dojo to use `object` tag? Right now it uses some strange `embed` tag...

Dojo version 1.7.2
documentation not that helpful http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/flash.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojox.embed.Flash is merely a browser sniffing utility which will present the `<embed>` or `<object>` in a way that suits the users browser the best.

Youre doing the wrong path, the Flash object would not know how to handle a streaming flv file, it needs to point to a swf.

#### Options to work with

```
var dataurl =    "player.swf"
var flashvars =  {'file':'playlist.xml','autostart':'true'};
var params =     {'allowfullscreen':'true','allowscriptaccess':'always', 'bgcolor':'#ffffff'};
var attributes = {'id': 'player1','name':'player1'};
var expressInstall = "http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/knowledgebase/index.cfm?id=6a253b75"
```

#### using swfobject with jwplayer

This is a sample from longtail showing howto embed via swfobject:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(dataurl, 'flashContent', '300', '250', '9', 'false', flashvars, params, attributes);
```

thus from the prototype embedSWF which is:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrlStr, replaceElemIdStr, widthStr, heightStr, 
     swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, flashvarsObj, parObj,
     attObj, callbackFn)
```

#### using dojox.embed.Flash with jwplayer

See [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/embed/Flash.html#constructor-parameters) for parameters

Mapping above results to

```
new Flash({
    width: 300,
    height: 250,
    minimumVersion: 9,
    expressInstall : expressInstall,
    allowScriptAccess: true,

    path: dataurl,
    id: 'player1',
    vars: flashvars,
    params: params        

}, 'flashContent');
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Path is correct. The problem seems to be lack of support for RTMP in DojoX Flash implementation – this is why jwplayer works fine dojo plugging doesn't.

Comment: no, youre just getting it wrong.. the Embed.Flash plugin writes html - it has no SWF capeabilities on its own (a SWF, which is a flash program, that in turn _could be a media player)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I realized it yesterday that I have to use some player.